# How to iterate over values of Map values

Tags: html, angular, typescript, object

I would like to fill of this  cells, this is initiall view of my app:

[image]

-> during app works for each rider rider's score will be fulfilled in such a way:

[image]

I have a .ts file where I put values of rider score (it's a map -> key is  heat number, value - score of particular rider) (if it will be both string or number depends on further configuration)

```
export const guests = {
    1: new Racer(9, 'Name_1', new Map([['1', 1], ['4', 2], ['7', 4]])),
    2: new Racer(10, 'Name_2', new Map([['1', 3], ['3', 4]])),
    3: new Racer(11, 'Name_3', new Map([['2', 3], ['6', 2]])),
    4: new Racer(12, 'Name_4', new Map([['6', 3], ['10', 3], ['13', 2]]))
};
```

I would like to get all values of map values in html, however I'm not able to iterate over values of this map.

**Further info**: There should be all the time displayed all  cells (it is designed that there should be exactly the same at the beginning
We don't know how entries for each racer there will be (probably for each rider this will be different)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let racer of team; let index = index">
      <td>{{racer.number}}</td>
      <td>{{racer.name}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="racer.places">{{racer.places.values().next().value}}</td>
       <td *ngIf="racer.places">{{racer.places.values().next().value}}</td>
       <td *ngIf="racer.places">{racer.places.values().next().value}}</td>
       <td *ngIf="racer.places">{racer.places.values().next().value}}</td>
       <td *ngIf="racer.places">{racer.places.values().next().value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**expected output**

- instead of only first entry there should be all values from Map

**working repo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterate-over-map-values

Comment: Also, racer 9 should not have the columns 2 & 3 filled up as well, since the next entry in the map for him is `[4,2]` - is that right?

Comment: key in the Map doesn't mean that it was his fourth score. It menas that he was ride in heat number 4. There are 15 heats, howvere we don't know in which exact heat the rider will participate. I would like to present racer number 9 and his scores which are 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: As well for racer number 9 the next entry may be ['5', hisNewScore]

Comment: It's my mistake. Of course it should be `Map<string, number>

Comment: I mean the way you are initializing it doesn't form a map at all. The proper structure would be `new Racer(9, "Name_1", { 1: 1, 4: 2, 7: 4 })`

Comment: Since the filed is `private _places?: Map<string, number>;` my IDE doesn't compile such entry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are initializing the map doesn't create a map after all. Make the following change to `guests`:

```
// now it actually contains key-value pairs

const guests = { 
  1: new Racer(9, "Name_1", { "1": 1, "4": 2, "7": 4 }),
  2: new Racer(10, "Name_2", { "1": 3, "3": 4 }),
  3: new Racer(11, "Name_3", { "2": 3, "6": 2 }),
  4: new Racer(12, "Name_4", { "6": 3, "10": 3, "13": 2 }),
};
```

now create a new property in the `team` object called *remaining*, this holds an array which contains the extra number of columns that are needed for each row. It is dynamically created for each racer.

```
team = Object.values(guests).map(racer => {
         return { 
           ...racer,
           remaining: new Array(5 - Object.values(racer.places).length)
         }
       });
```

and on the template, iterate over this newly created array for the remaining `<td>` that should be empty:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let racer of team">
            <td>{{racer.number}}</td>
            <td>{{racer.name}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let heat of racer.places | keyvalue">
                {{ heat.value }}
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let rem of racer.remaining" style="width: 10px;">
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works, however some diffculties occured:
1. I have to change this field from `private _score: Map<string, number>` into `private _score: { [heatNumber: string]: number };` - otherwise it doesn't work
2. There is some problem concerning number of cells, when I'm iterating and this field is empty there is no cells (there looked like they are merged) but I want them to be empty and in each row there should be exact number of cells available.

Comment: 1. For issue one, it would be better to declare it like that. 2 I've added a solution - it should work. Basically it creates a new property which contains the extra columns that should be generated for each row.

Comment: [working-stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterate-over-map-values-toprgp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

*This is some awful data structure to work with.*

Simply loop through the range that you need and check for each cell if the data exists with `.has()` method. Show the data in a ternary expression with `.get()` method if it exists, or `null` if it's missing.

Here is the HTML code that should work with your data structure:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>No.</td>
      <td>Racer</td>
      <td *ngFor="let p of [1,2,3,4,5]">{{p}}</td>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td *ngFor="let p of [6,7]">{{p}}</td>
      <td>Sum</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let racer of team; let index = index">
      <td>{{racer.number}}</td>
      <td>{{racer.name}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let p of [1,2,3,4,5]">{{racer.places.has(""+p) ? racer.places.get(""+p) : null}}</td>
      <td>TODO: Sum</td>
      <td *ngFor="let p of [6,7]">{{racer.places.has(""+p) ? racer.places.get(""+p) : null}}</td>
      <td>TODO: Sum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unless you are planning to expand the Racer class, I suggest you switch it to an **interface** and simply use JSON data structure with Objects instead of a Map

Comment: Quite nice, however it doesn't work in a way I expect. Because this code get only this scores when key in Map haas values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7.